# How to remove all html tags except img?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I got some html text, which contains all kinds of html tags, such as `<table>, <a>, <img>`,  and so on.

Now I want to use a regular expression to remove all the html tags, except `<img ...>` and `</img>`(and upper case `<IMG></IMG>`).

How to do this?

---

**UPDATE:**

My task is very simple, it just print the text content(including images) of a html as a summary in the front page, so I think regular expression is good and simple enough.

---

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Maybe a sample will make my question better to understand :)

There are some html text:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     Hello, everyone. Here is my photo: <img src="xxx.jpg" />. 
     And, <a href="xxx">know more</a> about me!
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to keep , and remove other tags. Following is what I want:

```
Hello, everyone. Here is my photo: <img src="xxx.jpg" />. And, know more about me!
```

Now I code like this:

```
html.replaceAll("<.*?>", "")
```

But it will remove all the content between `<` and `>`, but I want to keep `<img xxx>` and `</img>`, and remove the other content between `< and >`

Thank for everyone!

Comment: Step 1... don't use a regular expression :)

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this. What programming language are you using?

Comment: +1 as it is useful to know why you should not do this :)

Comment: For the love of God, why does everyone jump onto regular expressions to parse structured data? Exploit the structure. It's HTML that you're parsing my friend. Use an HTML parser. Stay away from regular expressions.

Comment: @Noufal, regular expression is good enough for this task. If I want **parse** a html page, I will use a parser. But what I want now is just removing some tags(content between `< and >`). Even if the regular express may break some content, that's acceptable.

Comment: You are *parsing* it (whether you're dropping tags after that or something else is irrelevant). It will be quicker to get a parser, parse your HTML and do what you want rather than create some dirty regexp to do the same thing. The more robust you make your regexp, the more unmaintainable it will be. Why do you *not* want to use a parser?

Comment: @Noufal, I used some kind of HTML parser in java, I think they are much complicated and lower performance than a simple regular expression. In my case, only 1 line of code with regular, can't be simpler. And the regex I found is also simple: `(?i)<(?!img|/img).*?>`

Comment: Your call. I still stand by my position that it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried a lot, this regular expression seems work for me:

```
(?i)<(?!img|/img).*?>
```

My code is:

```
html.replaceAll('(?i)<(?!img|/img).*?>', '');
```

Comment: Nice. +1. Can you please advise why I'm not seeing the replaceAll method though? What type is 'html'?

Comment: @freewind same here, cant see the replaceall working

Comment: @Faizan, The `html` should be a string of some html content, and the code should be Java (this is my very early question, I'm not sure I recall it correctly)

Answer (score 5):

Do not use a RegEx to parse HTML. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a compelling demonstration of why.

Use an HTML parser for your language/platform.

- [Here](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) is a java one (HTML parser)
- For .NET, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is recommended
- For ruby, there is [nokogiry](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2008/10/30/nokogiri-is-released/), though I am not a ruby dev, so don't know how good it is

Comment: @Oded, thank you. I don't parse the html, it is too heavy for my simple task. I think regex is the best tool for this, although I don't know how to write it :)

Comment: @Freewind - HTML is not a regular language, and _cannot_ be reliably parsed by RegEx, as the first link I posted demonstrates. You should use the right tool for the job. If you know _exactly_ what format your HTML will be coming in, string replace may even be enough...

Comment: I still want to use regex. I don't need exactly corret handling, it works most of time is OK

Comment: @PP - what _are_ you on? Bad day at the office? Looking at the question, my answer stands. For the kind of cleanup of arbitrary HTML that he wants, RegEx is not a good solution.

Comment: PP : Some specifics on why you feel the answer is inappropriate would be welcome. As it stands, your characterisation of the answer as "blind and unthinking" doesn't add anything to the discussion.

Comment: @Oded, I think your answer is helpful, and thank you for your work. Don't be sad

Comment: @Freewind - that's kind of you. I am not sad, I believe anyone is entitled to their own opinion, but would like to see something more than "you are wrong", a reasoned why would be good :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to why Do not use a RegEx is:

Regexp can't parse recursive grammar such as:

```
S -> (S)
S -> Empty
```

Because this kind of grammar has infinite state.

Since HTML has a recursive grammar you can simply use regexp.

```
SPAN -> <span>SPAN</span>
SPAN -> text
```

But in your case you can express a regular expression that is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<(img|IMG)*>*</(img|IMG)>
```

Comment: @mathk, thank you. You code is to match img tags(Am I right?), but what I want to do is match non-img tags.

Comment: @Freewind Then replace it by an empty string

Comment: @mathk, I want to keep img tags, and remove the other tags. (Maybe my poor English misguided you)

Comment: @Freewind Why would you want to match non-img. Simply match img and keep them. Either you tell what you want, either you tell what you don't want. In your case the thing you want is smaller to express then the thing you don't want.  (Unless the set your a talking is infinite but that is an other question you have to ask to Godël ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple using Regex:

```
const html = "<html>...</html>";
return html.replace(/<.*?>/ig, function (tag) {
  if (tag.indexOf('<img ') === 0) {
    return tag;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all html tags except the one below:**

```
<title>(.*?)<\/title>'
<meta name="description" content="(.*?)"/>'
<p>(.*?)<\/p>'
<h4 class="sc-jMKfon fhunKk">(.*?)<\/h4>'
<h2">(.*?)<\/h2>
<img(.*?)\/>
```

**FIND:** `<(?!\/?(title|meta|p|h2|img)\b)[^>]*>|<\/(?!title>|meta>|p>|h2>|>)[^>]+>`

**REPLACE BY:** `(leave empty)`